# Add the manu page to full screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, menu

i want to display this menu to full screen, i dont want to show the tab bar and the appbar, i want only the menu page in full screen.
when i click in `menu` (of botton navigation) show the full menu page
How can i do that!!! any help!

[image]

this is the code i used:

```
class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
                    Colors.lightBlue,
                    Colors.blue
                  ])
              ),
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/drawerHeader.png", height: 90, width: 90),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Flutter', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),)
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          CustomListTile(Icons.person, 'Profile', ()=>{
            Navigator.pop(ctxt),
            Navigator.push(ctxt,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Menu())
            )
          }),
          CustomListTile(Icons.notifications, 'Notification', ()=>{
            Navigator.pop(ctxt),
            Navigator.push(ctxt,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new NotificationView())
            )
          }),
          CustomListTile(Icons.settings, 'Settings', ()=>{}),
          CustomListTile(Icons.lock, 'Log Out', ()=>{}),
        ],

      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Stack` with a `Container()` (for transparent widget) and update that Container with your menu view  when click menu button.